# How to secure a webhook in Django using Stripe

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, payment

I have a webhook view which receives `POST` requests from a payment gateway. It identifies the customer and updates the amount with the provided data.

This can be exploited very easily if the webhook URL somehow gets leaked.

For e.g.

```
curl --data "cust_no=xxxxxxxxxx&amount=1000" https://example.com/wallet/payment_webhook/
```

How can I make it secure so that it doesn't accept such requests? It should validate that the request is coming only from the payment gateway.

Update:

The webhook request contains transaction details along with the customer number.

Comment: Hard to say without info on the model... what authorisation do you use? is the customer number the same as the `request.user`'s?

Comment: Yes. The payment gateway gives me transaction info along with the customer number.

Comment: I'd say that it's the responsibility of the gateway to properly authenticate itself. Consult its documentation. If you need help, please specify what payment gateway you are using.

Comment: agree with @AndreaCorbellini, like Paypal restricts users payment notification webhook to validate the data by posting back same data to another Paypal URL. So your payment gateway must have something like that in place.

Comment: I checked the Stripe documentation and there's nothing which handles it. Check it here https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Comment: Sometimes, you give the sender a secret "password" which they use to compute some sort of hash to send along with the request (e.g. HMAC digest).  On your side, you compute the same thing using the password you gave them and make sure that it matches.  That said, I have no idea how stripe handles it since I haven't used it myself. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's explicitly documented on the [webhooks documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks):

> **Best practices**
>
> [...]
>
> For optimum security, you can confirm the event data with Stripe before acting upon it. To do so:
>
> 1. Parse the JSON data as above.
> 2. Grab the received `Event` object ID value.
> 3. Use the `Event` object ID in a retrieve event API call.
> 4. Take action using the returned `Event` object.

See also [Webhook-Mailer](https://github.com/boucher/stripe-webhook-mailer) for a working example. Pay particular attention to [this line](https://github.com/boucher/stripe-webhook-mailer/blob/master/mailer.rb#L14):

```
# Retrieving the event from the Stripe API guarantees its authenticity  
event = Stripe::Event.retrieve(data[:id])
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll make the necessary changes.

Comment: In addition to this, you can also use HTTP basic auth, i.e. you'd set up your webhook endpoint in your Stripe settings to be https://username:password@yourserver.com/example.com/wallet/payment_webhook. In your event handler, you could then validate that the username and password you received are the same ones you set up in Stripe.